# Copy part of line from 1 text to 2nd text file

Tags: java, file

I am working on project where I need to copy some part of each line from 1st text file to other. In the first text each data is separated by splitter `--@` (which i have used).

I want to get the 1st two parts of actual 4 parts total of 3 splitters Ex:

```
Hello--@StackOverflow--@BMWCar--@Bye.
```

I just want to fetch 1st 2 parts .ie.

```
Hello--@StackOverflow
```

from all the lines of first text file to second text file. I have tried everything and could not get it to work. Please help me out of this. :)

Comment: You have problem with getting text from 1st or with saving part? Can you past here your code?

Comment: *I have tried everything* can you share some of it?

Comment: I didn't have any idea of how to do it. I was just trying to copy each column of data to different files and continue with the project which was not working(made things complicated). Thanks for the answers. It seriously helped me and also A4L thanks for the edit in question.(for rearranging it)(Not enough rep to vote up)

Comment: You accepted my answer and now it's not accepted. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry but its not working when the name contains dash(-) .ie. if `Hello--@StackOverflow--@BMWCar--@Bye.' conatains `He-llo--@StackOverflow--@BMWCar--@Bye.' is not working. (He-llo). There size is not being displayed                http://picpaste.com/Capture-Uuxd0Rkk.PNG

Comment: I've updated my code. Should work with names with a dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am little late, but below code will work as well :

```
String str = "Hello--@StackOverflow--@BMWCar--@Bye.";       
String strResult = str.split("(?<!\\G\\w+)(?:--@)")[0];
System.out.println(strResult);
```

`\G` is previous match, `(?<!regex)` is negative lookbehind.

**[Update]**

In your case, can we use below code? The solution is based on the file you provided

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.txt")); 
        String line; 
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf("--@")));
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I am only getting the first part of the string .ie. only   Hello. I also want StackOverflow

Comment: No, you must get "Hello--@StackOverflow". Just copy paste the code and try it.

Comment: `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("doc.txt"));
     String line;
     while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
     {
      //String str = "Hello--@StackOverflow--@BMWCar--@Bye.";
      String strResult = line.split("(?<!\\G\\w+)(?:--@)")[0];
      System.out.println(strResult);
     }`   Sorry! Your code is working but I have edited it and fetched from file. Here only hello is being displayed

Comment: May I get the content of file so that I can test?

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/8s6anbyf2sxz9yk/doc.txt?dl=0]. Sorry for late reply. Here is the file. I might be doing the mistake here Sir. Just help me out

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting names with dashes, it seems to me the best thing to use is String.split:

```
String test = "Hel-lo--@StackOverflow--@BMWCar--@Bye";

String[] sp = test.split("--@");

for(String name : Arrays.copyOfRange(sp, 0, 2))
{
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each line you read do the following:

```
String[] sp = line.split("--@",2);
String result = sp[0]+"--@"+sp[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

First, to get all the lines in the text file, try using a while loop. As you are reading in from one file, output to the second file. Split each line based on the conditional.

```
String inLine = in.nextLine();
String[] parts = inLine.split("--@");
String toWrite = parts[0] + " " + parts[1];
outLine.write(toWrite);
```

Should be easy enough to figure out.